# Does "the" C standard specify which standard a compiler has to adhere to?

Tags: c, gcc, standards

I just tried to compile a C program with a GNU compiler version 4.9.2. The source code contained a few `for int i=0; ...` statements and the compiler gave me an error and indicated that I should use `-std=c99` in order to compile *for loop initial declarations*. Apparently, such declarations were not valid before C99.

On an another machine, I have a more recent GNU compiler (8.1.1) where I can compile the same source code without explicitly specifying `-std=c99`.

Because GNU obviously made their compiler C99 compliant between 4.9.2 and 8.1.1, this lead me to the question if a recent C standard specified that a compiler has to adhere to C99 (or another standard).

Comment: GCC is not fully C99 compliant : standard pragmas [are still missing](https://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html) from GCC 8. C17 (or, rather, GNU's dialect known as `gnu17`) was simply chosen as the default for C code in newer GCC versions. The default C standard that the compiler chooses is up to the compiler.

Comment: gcc doesn't even claim to be a C compiler unless you pass `-pedantic` and one of the `-std=` options (or `-ansi`).

Comment: Side comment - Visual Studio keeps somewhat up to date with C++ compiler, but its C compiler is mostly C89 compliant (not C99).

Comment: DanielKamilKozar's reference to "newer GCC versions" means GCC 8 only at the time of this comment. GCC 5, 6, and 7 default to C11 (again, technically `gnu11`). C89/C90 (`gnu89`/`gnu90`) was the default in GCC 4 and earlier as far as I'm aware, meaning you'll get a compilation error if you even try to use `__STDC_VERSION__` since it wasn't added until 1994/1995 by Amendment 1 to the C89/C90 standard (which you can enable using `-std=iso9899:199409`).

Comment: @ChronoKitsune Well, you'll probably use `__STDC_VERSION__` in `#if`, and unknown identifiers there don't produce an error, they just turn into `0`.

Comment: @melpomene Fair enough. I just did `return __STDC_VERSION__` on the Compiler Explorer as a test of various versions, which obviously caused a compilation error since I'm not using it in `#if`. Sorry for the slightly misleading comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choosing whether to adhere to the C standard, or a particular version of it, is voluntary. The choice does not come from the C standard. It comes from outside. Anybody who makes a C implementation decides whether to conform to the 2018 C standard (or to conform mostly but not completely), whether to conform to the 2011 C standard, whether to conform to some “K&R” notion of C, or something else. Nothing in the C standard says, well, if you are conforming to this standard, your compiler has to conform to some previous version. The standard cannot actually require you to do anything until you **choose** to conform to the standard.

The C standard and the people who make it and the standards organizations that endorse and publish it have little power to make anybody do anything. They cannot publish the C standard and say you, [René Nyffenegger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180275/ren%C3%A9-nyffenegger), must obey the 2018 C standard. They are not law-making bodies. There are contracts between private parties which say some project will be produced in accordance to this standard or that standard, but those are private agreements, not public law.

In the 2018 C standard, paragraph 8 of the Foreword says:

> For an explanation of the voluntary nature of standards, the meaning of ISO specific terms and expressions related to conformity assessment, as well as information about ISO’s adherence to the World Trade Organization (WTO) principles in the Technical Barriers to Trade (TBT), see the following URL: [www.iso.org/iso/foreword.html](https://www.iso.org/iso/foreword.html).

Nor can the standard organizations prohibit you from writing a C compiler that does or does not conform to any particular version of the standard, nor from writing a compiler that conforms largely but not completely.

If you use the name of the C standard commercially, perhaps by claiming conformance to it, the standards organizations might have some legal rights in that regard. That involves international law and the law of many jurisdictions, which I cannot speak to authoritatively. I have not heard of any problems occurring from somebody claiming to conform to the C standard.

The standards organizations do officially withdraw old versions of the standards when a new version is published. This does not prevent you from writing a C implementation that conforms to an old version, but it would prevent you from claiming you are conforming to the current version when you are not. (For example, if a contract you agreed to required you to conform to the current C standard, that would change when the organization publishes a new version and withdraws the old one.)

Comment: I find the withdrawal of older C standards irksome, and inconsistent with the way other standards are handled.  When a new standard is introduced for a protocol like TCP/IP, SSL, etc., it will generally incorporate the older versions of the protocol.  Sometimes an older protocol may be deprecated, and support for it may eventually cease to be required (or--in rare cases--even allowed) but if a program's behavior has ever been defined by a standard, it should continue to be defined likewise except in rare cases (as with SSL) where technological forces would make it impossible...

Comment: ...for programs that conform to older standards to continue serving their intended purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Prior to GCC 5.0, the default standard it adhered (most closely) to was the C90 standard — specifying no standard was equivalent to specifying `-std=gnu90`.

From 5.0 onwards, the default was changed to the C11 standard — so specifying no standard was equivalent to specifying `-std=gnu11`.

Your two compiler versions show this behaviour.

Note that the C standard only prescribes what a compiler must do to adhere to that standard.  It does not mandate the behaviour of a compiler with respect to previous or future versions of the standard; there is only one version of the standard as far as the standard is concerned.  What compiler implementations do about other versions is entirely up to the compiler writers.

You can, of course, override the default behaviour of GCC with an explicit version:

- `-ansi`
- `-std=c90`
- `-std=c99`
- `-std=c11`
- `-std=gnu90`
- `-std=gnu99`
- `-std=gnu11`
- … and some other variations …

The `-ansi` option is equivalent to `-std=c90`.  The difference between the `-std=cXX` and `-std=gnuXX` is that the `c` version doesn't set the macros for various extensions, so you might have to explicitly indicate that you want to use POSIX interfaces, for example, with options such as `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700`, whereas with `gnu` version sets those macros automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The each version of the C Standard classifies implementations into two categories: those which comply with that particular version of the Standard, and those that don't.  There aren't any C Language Police who will break the kneecaps of anyone who sells non-conforming implementation.  Indeed, there are some situations where a non-conforming implementation would be more useful than any conforming implementation could be (e.g. on some small embedded platforms, the amount of code required to produce a full conforming implementation of "printf" might exceed the total code space available).  Further, there is no guarantee that a every conforming implementation will be suitable for any particular purpose (indeed, it would be possible to contrive a C implementation which was unsuitable for any purpose whatsoever except to demonstrate that the C Standard doesn't mandate usefulness).

Most quality C development systems can be invoked in different modes which may conform (or fail to conform) with different versions of the Standard, and may be suitable (or unsuitable) for various purposes.  From the point of view of the Standard, every different mode in which a development system can be invoked would be a different implementation.  I think it would be useful to have the Standard to sub-categorize implementations based upon their support (or lack thereof) for popular features or guarantees that would make them suitable (or unsuitable) for common purposes (e.g. low-level or systems programming) but as yet the Standard has not done so.